# create new column based on other column values after iterating through multiple lists

Tags: python, list, loops, dataframe

I have a dataframe that includes a column with multiple foods items. I want to create a new column with the food item type, which is stored in multiple lists.

Here are my lists:

```
fruits = ['apples', 'oranges', 'bananas']
veggies = ['carrots', 'lettuce', 'onions']
meats = ['steak', 'chicken', 'fish']
```

I have a column that contains all of these food items, but not want to create a column that has the food types.

I have a pretty clunky solution to do this, but I was wondering if there is an easier way to iterate through these lists and append the food type to the new column.

Here is my current solution:

```
df['food_type'] = np.where(df['foods'].isin(fruits),'fruits',
                        (np.where(df['foods'].isin(veggies),'veggies',                            
                        (np.where(df['foods'].isin(meats),'meats','other')))))
```

Would it better to create a dictionary containing the lists and iterate through that? i.e.

```
food_types ={'fruits':['apples','oranges','bananas'],'veggies':['carrots', 'lettuce', 'onions'],'meats': ['steak', 'chicken', 'fish']}
```

Comment: You probably want `np.select` instead of `np.where`

Comment: I think you can also achieve this by creating a temp df and using `join`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just put your data into a dictionary as you suggested in your OP:

```
import pandas as pd

fruits = ['apples', 'oranges', 'bananas']
veggies = ['carrots', 'lettuce', 'onions']
meats = ['steak', 'chicken', 'fish']

data = {'fruits': fruits, 'veggies': veggies, 'meats': meats}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Yields:

```
    fruits  veggies    meats
0   apples  carrots    steak
1  oranges  lettuce  chicken
2  bananas   onions     fish
```

Per your comment, this will not work if the list are of different lengths. Using your original dataframe format, you could do the following with `apply()`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(fruits + veggies + meats, columns=['foods'])

def find_category(x):

  return [k for k, v in data.items() if x in v][0]

df['food_type'] = df['foods'].apply(find_category)
```

Yields:

```
     foods food_type
0   apples    fruits
1  oranges    fruits
2  bananas    fruits
3  carrots   veggies
4  lettuce   veggies
5   onions   veggies
6    steak     meats
7  chicken     meats
8     fish     meats
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if my lists are of different lengths? thats not the case in the example I provided but thats what I will be dealing with.

Comment: Good question, I have added another option above. This assumes that the query will only fall into a single category however. If it falls into multiple categories (i.e. is associated with multiple keys in your dictionary), then it will return the first matching key.

Comment: thanks! i think this will do the trick, or at least give me a dataframe i can then merge to my larger, original one

Comment: i dont have a high enough reputation yet, but i will as soon as i do. thank again for your help